# remote akka actors not working on play frameworks

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.2

this is my first post on stackoverflow, and english is not my native language, so apologize if there are mistakes in the post.

I am trying to run remote actors with play framework, but I can't make them work properly. 
it is a simple client-server system, and both systems are in separate proyects.

client controller index function is something like:

```
val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
val servidorRyP = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://Servidor@127.0.0.1:5000/user/servidorRyP")
servidorRyP ! id.toString
```

and akka configuration in conf file for the client:

```
#akka
akka.default-dispatcher.core-pool-size-max = 64
akka.debug.receive = on

akka {
actor {
//provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
```

}

if I uncomment the provider file, it show and error: "NoSuchMethodException: akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.", so I left ir commented.

By other side, server controller declares the actor and starts it:

```
val system = ActorSystem("Servidor")
val servidor = system.actorOf(Props[ServidorRyP], name = "servidorRyP")
```

I am able to send messages to the actor from the Server application, but I can't reach it from the client.

the akka configuration on Server conf file is:

```
akka {
actor {
//provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
deployment {
/servidorRyP {
remote = "akka.tcp://Servidor@127.0.0.1:5000"
}
}
}
}
```

When I execute both applications (in diferent ports) with play, launching the server before the client, It does nothing, I mean that the client seems to execute the code, but the server does not receive anything.

I am using Play for Mac, but as far as i know, there are no firewall problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add `akka-remote` to your dependencies?  It's not included by default.

Add:

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.2.3"
```

to your build file.

Comment: HI, thaks for the response, I already added that in the sbt file, but it still not working. version was not the same, I had 2.1.0 instead I think. Does that matters? It is the same version for client and server.

Comment: NoSuchMethodException indicates that you are mixing incompatible versions. Use the version that is compatible with the Play version you are using. For Play 2.2.x it is Akka 2.2.4.